# Nested Routes can not index all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes, nested

I have nested routes as follows;

```
resources :boats, except: :destroy do
      resources :pictures
  end
```

So user can upload picture and everything works fine. But `picture/index.html.erb`. I can not see all the pictures. It returns nil. But I can see pictures in the database. Probably because I try to retrieve wrong parameter.

When I take out the if statement `<% if @pictures.present? %>` it throws and error;

```
NoMethodError in PicturesController#create
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
```

Here is `#index view`;

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Pictures#index!</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pictures/index.html.erb</p>


<% if @pictures.present? %> <!-- Returns nil-->
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
</br>
<%= pic.name %>
<%= image_tag pic.image_url(:thumb).to_s  %>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture) %> |
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@boat, @picture], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td> | 
</br>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture) %> |
</br>
</br>
<%= link_to "add", new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture) %>

</div>
```

So here, picture.present returns always nil, so I can not display any images.

Here is `pictures controller`;

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_filter :load_parent

  def index
    @pictures = @boat.pictures.all
  end

  def new
    @picture = @boat.pictures.new
  end

  def show
    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create

    @picture = @boat.pictures.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      #flash[:success] = "Continue from here"
      render 'index'
      #redirect_to boat_path(@boat)
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def edit
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])

    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated picture."
      render 'index'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed picture."
    redirect_to boat_path(@boat)
  end


  private

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :image)
    end

    def load_parent
     @boat = Boat.find(params[:boat_id])
    end

end
```

EDIT 1:
Log;

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i3FW1zbhoGW2vavipN9NJ2Fvi9R1Lk/CKDsAttuqHWb8rFNmJgXpjE2D25oAqJ3xp9BXAnd0kDmrdIxhn1Qrpw==", "picture"=>{"name"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb4a5f50f30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/w0/703ccggs56l3hrc79h3rdylm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150423-5028-1rbpgnj.jpg>, @original_filename="imgres-4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[image]\"; filename=\"imgres-4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Done", "controller"=>"pictures", "action"=>"create", "boat_id"=>"114"}
```

EDIT 2:

if I add `@pictures = @boat.pictures.all` to create that is fine, but all pics have its own destroy button.And when I look at them all shows the same address, so clicking to destroy, destroys all of them;

All of the destroy ids are the same. I though index action lists all and destroy erases individually. This case is same for edit action too

[image]

EDIT 3:

```
#boats controller

class BoatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update]

  def new
    @boat = Boat.new
  end

  def create
   @boat = current_user.boats.new(boat_params) if logged_in?
    if @boat.save
      #flash[:success] = "Continue from here"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def show
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])

  end


  def edit
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
     @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
    if @boat.update_attributes(boat_params)
      flash[:success] = "The Boat Saved"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def update_years
  # updates year and model based on brand selected
  brand = Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand_name])
  # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
  @years = brand.years.map{|a| [a.name, a.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Year") #use a.name here instead of a.id
  @models   = brand.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")#use s.name here instead of s.id
  end

  def update_models
  # updates model based on year selected
  year = Year.find_by_name(params[:year_name])
  @models = year.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Model") #use s.name here instead of s.id
  end



private

    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model, :captained, :boat_type, :daily_price, :boat_length, :listing_tagline, :listing_description, :boat_category, :hull_material, :mast_material)
    end


end
```

Comment: What URL are you visiting ?

Comment: ....`boats/boat_id/pictures`, so it is `index.html.erb`

Comment: check what comes in params in load_parent.

Comment: Could it be that @boat is already nil, thus delivers a nil object to @pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `@pictures` in your create action.
You can try:

```
  def create

    @picture = @boat.pictures.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      #flash[:success] = "Continue from here"
      @pictures = @boat.pictures.all  
      render 'index'
      #redirect_to boat_path(@boat)
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end
```

For buttons:

```
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
</br>
<%= pic.name %>
<%= image_tag pic.image_url(:thumb).to_s  %>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, pic) %> |
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', boat_picture_path(@boat, pic), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td> | 
</br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried but then I get error, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PicturesController#destroy
Couldn't find Picture with 'id'=186 [WHERE "pictures"."boat_id" = ?]

Comment: and check if that picture exist in your db

Comment: ok, i found the error, after creating new boat, it worked, but i can not redirect to index page after destroy a picture. It gives an error...NoMethodError in PicturesController#destroy
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ok. adding `@pictures = @boat.pictures.all ` to both `destroy` and `create` solved the problem. But it disturbs me to use `@pictures` twice, is there another way?

Comment: It is because you are rendering `'index'` page but you better should `redirect_to` it

Comment: So I should use, `redirect_to 'index'` ?

Comment: `redirect_to boat_pictures_path(@boat)`